# How to make "you died" symbol when you die

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I tried making a game but I can't the "you died" symbol to work. I don't know how to use JavaScript to create my text inside the canvas.

Also, is there a way to create a `myBlockPad` variable that stops you from going through it but still lets you move elsewhere?

```js
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacle;
var myBlockPad;

function startGame() {
  myGamePiece = new component(40, 40, "#00ff00ff", 50, 140);
  myObstacle = new component(10, 200, "#cf0000ff", 300, 120);
  myBlockPad = new component(40, 80, "#7e3f00", 0, 120);
  myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 560;
    this.canvas.height = 320;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      myGameArea.key = false;
    })
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  },
  stop: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    document.createElement("/* this is where the game over text goes*/").innerHTML;
  }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
  this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
      crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
  }
}

function updateGameArea() {
  if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
    myGameArea.stop();
  } else {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myObstacle.update();
    myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
    myGamePiece.y += myGamePiece.speedY;
  }
  if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37 || myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 65) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = -3;
  } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39 || myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 68) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 3;
  } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 38 || myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 87) {
    myGamePiece.speedY = -3;
  } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 40 || myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 83) {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 3;
  } else {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
  }
  myGamePiece.update();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style>
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="startGame()">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ctx.fillText(text,xAxis,yAxis);
```

E.g. `ctx.fillText("You died",50,50);`

Change colour is `ctx.fillStyle="red";`
Change font and size = `ctx.font="30px Arial";`

Comment: How do you change color, font family and size?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include your additional requests.

Comment: 1 line after `ctx.fillText("You died",50,50);`

Comment: So is the fillText working? They should go before the fillText line.

Comment: yeah, but `fillStyle` and `font` aren't.

Comment: Put them in the line before fillText. The font and colour needs to be defined before the text is drawn.

Comment: Brilliant! Please upvote and mark as correct if this works then.